# jQuery noobie can't make a checked checkbox show an alert

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I found this answer before, to fire an alert if the button is pressed but the checkbox isn't checked.

Why won't this work?

I have this in the head

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

And this in the body:

```
<input value="1"  type="checkbox" name="salgsvilkar" ID="checkbox2"  style="float:left;"
       onclick="document.getElementById('scrollwrap').style.cssText='border-color:#85c222; background-color:#E5F7C7;';" /><label for="checkbox2" class="akslabel">Salgs og leveringsvilkår er lest og akseptert</label>
        </span>

         {literal}
            <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   //checkbox
   $("#checkbox2").click(function(){
       //if this...
       //alert("this")...
       if($("#checkbox2").is(':checked'))
       {              
          alert("im checked");
       }
   });
   //button
   $("#fullfor_btn").click(function(e){
       if(!$("#checkbox2").is(':checked'))
       {
           alert("you did not check the agree to terms..."); 
           e.preventDefault();
       }
   });
 }
</script>
  {/literal}
```

This on another .tpl:

```
<label></label>
        <button type="submit" class="submit" name="{$method}" id="fullfor_btn" title="Fullfør bestillingen nå" value="">&nbsp;</button>
```

What could be going wrong? The jQuery doesn't fire anything at all.

**update** the id terms was changed to checkbox2, still nothing happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to fire an alert if the button is
>   pressed but the checkbox isn't
>   checked.

Try this if you press but the check box is **not checked** as you said above:

```
 $("#checkbox2").click(function(){
   if($("#checkbox2").is(':checked') == false)
   {              
      alert("im checked");
   }
 });
```

.

**Updated based on comment:**

To show an alert if checked, you can simple do like:

```
 $("#checkbox2").click(function(){
   if($("#checkbox2").is(':checked'))
   {              
      alert("im checked");
   }
 });
```

Also from your code, it seems that you are missing the `);` at the end for the:

```
$(function()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm totally new to jQuery, but also there's some in there to say that if it is checked, show an alert.. But that doesn't happen either.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: you are missing `);` at the end, see my asnwer plz

Comment: Aha! Thanks :) One more thing, can I add more than one function to the selector?

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: yes you can.

Comment: :) Great, I'll see if I can add one, will probably be back here in a while to ask what's going wrong with that haha.

Answer (score 2):

Your checkbox has the id "checkbox2", but you are trying to access it using the id "terms" in the click handler for the button.

#### update

You are missing the closing parenthesis for the `$(function(){...})` call. This throws a syntax error when the page is loaded, and the code in the script block is never run. Change the last line in the script block from:

```
}
```

to:

```
});
```

I have tested the code with this change, and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkbox2").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
      alert("im checked");
    }
  });

  $("#fullfor_btn").click(function(e) {
    if ($("#checkbox2").attr("checked") == false) {
      alert("you did not check the agree to terms..."); 
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any element with `id="terms"` in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks, just changed it and updated the question, but it still won't fire.